# How to connect Web Audio API to Tone.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, web-audio-api, tone.js

I'm doing an *Online Audio Player*, so I want to integrate **Pitch Shifter** in my App, which is available on **Tone js** but not in **Web Audio API**...

So my idea is to connect *Tonejs* **Pitch Shifter** to *Web Audio API's audioContext*.

Is there any possible ways?

*Here is my code for a reference*

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);

var mediaElem = document.querySelector('audio');

var stream = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mediaElem);

var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

stream.connect(gainNode);

// tone js

var context = new Tone.Context(audioCtx); // Which is Mentioned in Tonejs Docs!

var pitchShift = new Tone.PitchShift().toMaster();

pitchShift.connect(gainNode);

// Gives Error!
gainNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you want to achieve a signal flow like this:

```
mediaElement > gainNode > pitchShift > destination
```

To make sure Tone.js is using the same AudioContext you can assign it by using the setter on the Tone object. This needs to be done before doing anything else with Tone.js.

```
Tone.context = context;
```

Tone.js also exports a helper which can be used to connect native AudioNodes to the nodes provided by Tone.js.

```
Tone.connect(gainNode, pitchShift);
```

I modified your example code a bit to incorporate the changes.

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
var mediaElem = document.querySelector('audio');
var stream = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(mediaElem);
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();

// This a normal connection between to native AudioNodes.
stream.connect(gainNode);

// Set the context used by Tone.js
Tone.context = audioCtx;

var pitchShift = new Tone.PitchShift();

// Use the Tone.connect() helper to connect native AudioNodes with the nodes provided by Tone.js
Tone.connect(gainNode, pitchShift);
Tone.connect(pitchShift, audioCtx.destination);
```

Comment: Thanks Dude @chrisguttandin! You helped me alot!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Please go ahead and accept the answer if you think it is correct. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: If your new Tone node is meant to be placed in the middle of your graph, you can spare multiple `Tone.connect`  calls and use the `.chain` method present in every Tone audio node. In this example we would replace the last line with `pitchShift.chain(audioCtx.destination)`, but the idea is that this method takes in a variable number of audio nodes as arguments, and they are all connected sequentially, in arguments order.

Comment: As of Tone version `14.7.77` you should use `Tone.setContext(audioCtx)` instead of `Tone.context = audioCtx`